# Color portions of sf LINESTRING by variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I would like color different portions of an `sf` LINESTRING using a variable with `ggplot` and `geom_sf`. I can do something similar using `geom_path`, but in `geom_sf` a similar approach does not appear to work. Can someone offer a possible approach?

Sample Data

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)



df <- tibble(time = seq(1,21),
             lon = seq(-50,-30, 1) + rnorm(n = 21),
             lat = seq(10, 20, 0.5) + rnorm(n = 21),
             type = c(rep('A',5),rep('B',10), rep('A',6)))
```

**Using tibble/dataframe:**
Using a tibble and a basic ggplot I can do this, incorporating `group = 1` and a single line will be drawn with different sections colored by `type`. This is the type of plot I would like to make, but using an `sf` object instead.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_path(data = df, 
            aes(lon, lat, color = type, group = 1))
```

**Using `sf` object/LINESTRING**

If I cast to a LINESTRING using the `group_by` and `type` I end up with two LINESTRINGs

```
df_sf <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c('lon','lat')) %>%
  st_set_crs(.,value = 4326) %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarize(do_union = TRUE) %>%
  st_cast(.,'LINESTRING')
```

And then when I do variations on the code below I end up with two separate lines and the two portions with type = A are connected.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = df_sf, 
            aes(color = type, group = 1))
```

Is there a way to achieve the `ggplot + geom_path()` type behavior, using a `geom_sf()` approach (so I can project the variables, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an approach that splits a line into segments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55961448/8449629), but that may be overkill for your use case...

Try this:

```
df_sf <- df %>%
  
  # ensure data is sorted along x-axis
  arrange(lon) %>%
  
  # detect each time type changes, & create a duplicate point with previous type
  mutate(change.type = tidyr::replace_na(lag(type) != type, FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(type = ifelse(change.type,
                       paste(lag(type), type, sep = ";"),
                       type) %>%
           strsplit(";")) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(cols = c(type)) %>%
  
  # create new group column that increments with every colour change
  mutate(change.type = tidyr::replace_na(lag(type) != type, FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(new.type = cumsum(change.type)) %>%
  
  st_as_sf(coords = c('lon', 'lat')) %>%
  st_set_crs(., value = 4326) %>%
  
  # group by both original type (for colour) & new type (for group)
  group_by(type, new.type) %>% 
  summarize(do_union = TRUE) %>%
  st_cast(.,'LINESTRING') %>%
  ungroup()
```

Compare results

```
cowplot::plot_grid(
  ggplot() +
    geom_path(data = arrange(df, lon), 
              aes(lon, lat, color = type, group = 1), size = 1) +
    ggtitle("geom_path approach") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom"),
  
  ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = df_sf, 
            aes(color = type, group = new.type), size = 1) +
    ggtitle("geom_sf approach") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom"),

  nrow = 1
)
```

[image: result]

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(time = seq(1,21),
             lon = seq(-50,-30, 1) + rnorm(n = 21),
             lat = seq(10, 20, 0.5) + rnorm(n = 21),
             type = c(rep('A', 5), rep('B', 10), rep('A', 6)))
```