# Split linestring with points and assign new segment ID in R

Tags: r, split, point, r-sf, sfnetwork

I am trying to split a river (lines) using dams (points) into connected segments between the dams.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55519152/split-line-by-multiple-points-using-sf-package) is the closest to what I'm trying to achieve. The problem is that `st_split` uses the polygon boundaries as the 'blade' thus splitting one line into three rather than two. I'd also like to assign a common ID to the line sections between each point.

Desired output

[image: Ideal points splitting lines and assigning same ID to connected segments.]

Here's what I've tried. For this example the result should have 9 features.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)

buf_all <- st_buffer(pt, 0.001)
parts <- st_collection_extract(lwgeom::st_split(ln$geometry, buf_all), "LINESTRING")

parts_all <- st_as_sf(
  data.frame(
    id = 1:length(parts),
    geometry = parts
  )
)
```

But the result isn't as expected.

```
>nrow(parts_all)
[1] 13  2
```

Data

```
  ln <- structure(list(River_ID = c(159, 160, 161, 186, 196), geometry = structure(list(
            structure(c(289924.625, 289924.5313, 289922.9688, 289920.0625, 
            289915.7499, 289912.7188, 289907.4375, 289905.3438, 289901.1251, 
            289889, 289888.5, 289887.5938, 289886.5, 289886.4063, 289885.3124, 
            289884.0938, 289884.0001, 289882.8125, 289881.625, 289878.6875, 
            289877.9688, 289876.25, 289874.5625, 289874.25, 289872.7188, 
            289871.2813, 289871.1875, 289870.0313, 289869, 289868.5939, 
            289867.8436, 289865.8438, 289864.0625, 289862.5939, 289862.375, 
            289861.5, 289860.7812, 289860.5625, 289859.5313, 289858.375, 
            289857.7813, 289855.4063, 289854.25, 289850.8749, 289846.4376, 
            289841.9064, 289836.0625, 289828.1562, 289822.8438, 289816.625, 
            289812.4376, 289807.9064, 289798.75, 289793.125, 289786.2188, 
            289781.375, 289777.3124, 289770.0313, 289765.4375, 289762.2188, 
            289759.25, 289755.5938, 289753.0625, 289747.9687, 289743.7499, 
            289741.5938, 289739.5, 289736.1874, 289732.75, 289727, 289723.7499, 
            289719.625, 289715.5626, 289713.7499, 202817.531300001, 202817.2031, 
            202815.1094, 202812.468699999, 202809.3906, 202806.7656, 
            202799.7969, 202797.906300001, 202794.093800001, 202783.515699999, 
            202783.125, 202782.4844, 202781.906300001, 202781.8125, 202781.3594, 
            202781.093800001, 202780.9999, 202780.5469, 202780, 202777.625, 
            202777.0469, 202775.718800001, 202774.1875, 202773.906300001, 
            202772.1875, 202770.4531, 202770.25, 202768.5156, 202766.6719, 
            202766, 202764.0469, 202759.6719, 202755.8749, 202752.781300001, 
            202752.1875, 202749.953199999, 202748.297, 202747.906300001, 
            202746.0625, 202744.2344, 202743.5625, 202740.4375, 202738.8125, 
            202734.5, 202727.9844, 202723.5625, 202719.1875, 202714.9845, 
            202713.031300001, 202710.6875, 202710.0469, 202711.406300001, 
            202714.5626, 202716.9845, 202718.718900001, 202719.5469, 
            202718.734300001, 202716.4531, 202715.125, 202713.7344, 202712.093800001, 
            202709.8749, 202708.875, 202709.2655, 202710.7031, 202712.375, 
            202712.375, 202712.2344, 202711.0469, 202707.906300001, 202705.406300001, 
            202703.0469, 202701.468800001, 202700.7656), .Dim = c(74L, 
            2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(289954.375, 
            289953.5, 289950.6562, 289949.7499, 289949, 289948.125, 289946.0625, 
            289945.9688, 289944.5313, 289943.4063, 289941.3438, 289939.4375, 
            289937.4375, 289935.1875, 289932.75, 289930.625, 289928.8125, 
            289928.25, 289926.7188, 289925.5313, 289925.7813, 289925.625, 
            289925.4063, 289925.1251, 289924.625, 202872.75, 202872.031400001, 
            202868.7031, 202867.343699999, 202864.906199999, 202861.515699999, 
            202858.297, 202854.406300001, 202851.9375, 202849.468800001, 
            202847.703, 202846.75, 202845.4531, 202843.6719, 202843.0625, 
            202841.593900001, 202839.7344, 202839.2344, 202838, 202835.9375, 
            202832.875, 202825.7344, 202822.9531, 202819.4531, 202817.531300001
            ), .Dim = c(25L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg"
            )), structure(c(290042.6563, 290042.3437, 290041.5313, 290038.4376, 
            290037.625, 290036.5313, 290035.5313, 290034.8438, 290034.5313, 
            290033.7188, 290032.9375, 290032.125, 290030.3437, 290030.0313, 
            290028.625, 290027.5626, 290027.3438, 290026.7188, 290024.5313, 
            290023.625, 290020.625, 290018.0001, 290014.9375, 290012.0938, 
            290008.5625, 290004.375, 290000.0001, 289999.875, 289997.625, 
            289993.7188, 289990.5, 289987.1562, 289985.4063, 289980.375, 
            289973.3124, 289966.375, 289961.8438, 289959, 289954.375, 
            202884.0625, 202884.25, 202884.843800001, 202888.4531, 202889.75, 
            202891.0469, 202892.0469, 202892.656300001, 202892.843800001, 
            202893.2501, 202893.5469, 202893.656300001, 202893.4531, 
            202893.4531, 202893.343699999, 202893.093800001, 202893.0469, 
            202892.843800001, 202891.953199999, 202891.5469, 202889.843800001, 
            202888.218800001, 202885.1094, 202880.9219, 202877.5625, 
            202873.968800001, 202872.5469, 202872.5156, 202872.625, 202874.5469, 
            202876.734300001, 202878.1719, 202877.953199999, 202876.3125, 
            202873.468800001, 202872.031400001, 202872.906199999, 202873.0781, 
            202872.75), .Dim = c(39L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
            "sfg")), structure(c(290054.125, 290053.4375, 290052.5313, 
            290051.625, 290050.0313, 290048.125, 290044.125, 290040.4376, 
            290039.4375, 290036.9688, 290031.4375, 290027.5312, 290024.8125, 
            290021.7499, 290020.9688, 290018.3437, 290015, 290010.25, 
            290006.0313, 290002.4376, 290000.0001, 289999.2187, 289996.6875, 
            289995.3438, 289994.125, 289991.1875, 289989.2187, 289987.9688, 
            289986.125, 289980.5313, 289975.0314, 289970.9063, 289968.5625, 
            289961.0312, 289948.0001, 289939.625, 289933.1563, 289928.3125, 
            289926.5313, 289924.625, 202835.953199999, 202835.656300001, 
            202835.4531, 202835.343699999, 202835.5469, 202835.7656, 
            202836.25, 202836.4531, 202836.5469, 202836.5469, 202835.953199999, 
            202836.031400001, 202836.625, 202837.7969, 202838.4844, 202839.343699999, 
            202836.25, 202832.7656, 202832.3125, 202833.4844, 202834.4844, 
            202834.8125, 202834.2344, 202832.625, 202830.625, 202828.593800001, 
            202828.968800001, 202831.0625, 202833.2655, 202835.5781, 
            202838, 202838.906199999, 202839.125, 202836.4531, 202830.781300001, 
            202827.093800001, 202823.625, 202818.5, 202817.5625, 202817.531300001
            ), .Dim = c(40L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg"
            )), structure(c(290042.625, 290042.0313, 290041.2187, 290040.3125, 
            290038.4063, 290037.7188, 290035.8125, 290033.7188, 290030.9063, 
            290028.2187, 290021.5313, 290021.2187, 290014.2188, 290013.4063, 
            290012.3125, 290010.0625, 290007.9375, 290005.9688, 290004.125, 
            290000.0001, 289999.4063, 289998.3125, 289997.5312, 289996.8438, 
            289993.625, 289993.0314, 289989.7188, 289989.3438, 289987.625, 
            289987.2187, 289984.0313, 289978.125, 289977.9375, 289974.3437, 
            289972.7188, 289970.9375, 289967.9375, 289965.2187, 289965.1563, 
            289962.3437, 289960.5313, 289959.1251, 289959.0314, 289959.3438, 
            289959.4375, 289959.4375, 289959.3438, 289959.2187, 289958.9375, 
            289958.5313, 289956.125, 289954.375, 202953.781300001, 202952.4844, 
            202951.281300001, 202950.0781, 202948.1875, 202947.5781, 
            202945.8749, 202944.281300001, 202941.781300001, 202940.1875, 
            202936.375, 202936.1875, 202931.968800001, 202931.4844, 202930.875, 
            202929.093800001, 202927.1094, 202925.031300001, 202922.734300001, 
            202917.2031, 202916.4375, 202915.2031, 202914.5469, 202914.4531, 
            202911.4531, 202910.843800001, 202908.0469, 202907.75, 202906.75, 
            202906.5469, 202904.843800001, 202901.843800001, 202901.75, 
            202900.0469, 202899.156400001, 202898.0469, 202894.656300001, 
            202892.0469, 202891.9844, 202889.343699999, 202887.656300001, 
            202885.75, 202884.5469, 202883.343699999, 202882.5469, 202881.343699999, 
            202880.0469, 202879.343699999, 202877.656300001, 202876.25, 
            202874.25, 202872.75), .Dim = c(52L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
            "LINESTRING", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(
            input = "OSGB 1936 / British National Grid", wkt = "PROJCRS[\"OSGB 1936 / British National Grid\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"OSGB 1936\",\n        DATUM[\"OSGB 1936\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"Airy 1830\",6377563.396,299.3249646,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4277]],\n    CONVERSION[\"British National Grid\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",49,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",-2,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9996012717,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",400000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",-100000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"UK - Britain and UKCS 49Â°46'N to 61Â°01'N, 7Â°33'W to 3Â°33'E\"],\n        BBOX[49.75,-9.2,61.14,2.88]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",27700]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", 
        "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 289713.7499, 
        ymin = 202700.7656, xmax = 290054.125, ymax = 202953.781300001
        ), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("sf", 
        "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(River_ID = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", 
        "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))
    
 pt <- structure(list(lat = c(202805.8942, 202836.136, 202872.9487, 
        202905.3284), lng = c(289912.0584, 290014.8446, 290001.2364, 
        289984.9382), id = 1:4, geometry = structure(list(structure(c(289912.058400425, 
        202805.894199679), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(290014.844597566, 
        202836.136003318), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(290001.236395958, 
        202872.948712436), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(289984.938209474, 
        202905.32838227), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(
            input = "OSGB 1936 / British National Grid", wkt = "PROJCRS[\"OSGB 1936 / British National Grid\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"OSGB 1936\",\n        DATUM[\"OSGB 1936\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"Airy 1830\",6377563.396,299.3249646,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4277]],\n    CONVERSION[\"British National Grid\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",49,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",-2,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9996012717,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",400000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",-100000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"UK - Britain and UKCS 49Â°46'N to 61Â°01'N, 7Â°33'W to 3Â°33'E\"],\n        BBOX[49.75,-9.2,61.14,2.88]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",27700]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
        "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 289912.058400425, 
        ymin = 202805.894199679, xmax = 290014.844597566, ymax = 202905.32838227
        ), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("sf", 
        "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(lat = NA_integer_, 
        lng = NA_integer_, id = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", 
        "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will present a solution based on a new `R` package called `sfnetworks`. For the moment, it's not on CRAN, but you can install it as follows:

```r
install.packages("remotes"); library("remotes")
install_github("luukvdmeer/sfnetworks")
```

The last step is not really ideal since it involves a manual operation. It works for this example, but it isn't easy to generalise it to larger networks.

Anyway, in the first step, I load packages and data.

```r
library(sf)
library(sfnetworks)
library(dplyr)
library(tmap)

ln <- structure(list(River_ID = c(159, 160, 161, 186, 196), geometry = structure(list(
  structure(c(
    289924.625, 289924.5313, 289922.9688, 289920.0625,
    289915.7499, 289912.7188, 289907.4375, 289905.3438, 289901.1251,
    289889, 289888.5, 289887.5938, 289886.5, 289886.4063, 289885.3124,
    289884.0938, 289884.0001, 289882.8125, 289881.625, 289878.6875,
    289877.9688, 289876.25, 289874.5625, 289874.25, 289872.7188,
    289871.2813, 289871.1875, 289870.0313, 289869, 289868.5939,
    289867.8436, 289865.8438, 289864.0625, 289862.5939, 289862.375,
    289861.5, 289860.7812, 289860.5625, 289859.5313, 289858.375,
    289857.7813, 289855.4063, 289854.25, 289850.8749, 289846.4376,
    289841.9064, 289836.0625, 289828.1562, 289822.8438, 289816.625,
    289812.4376, 289807.9064, 289798.75, 289793.125, 289786.2188,
    289781.375, 289777.3124, 289770.0313, 289765.4375, 289762.2188,
    289759.25, 289755.5938, 289753.0625, 289747.9687, 289743.7499,
    289741.5938, 289739.5, 289736.1874, 289732.75, 289727, 289723.7499,
    289719.625, 289715.5626, 289713.7499, 202817.531300001, 202817.2031,
    202815.1094, 202812.468699999, 202809.3906, 202806.7656,
    202799.7969, 202797.906300001, 202794.093800001, 202783.515699999,
    202783.125, 202782.4844, 202781.906300001, 202781.8125, 202781.3594,
    202781.093800001, 202780.9999, 202780.5469, 202780, 202777.625,
    202777.0469, 202775.718800001, 202774.1875, 202773.906300001,
    202772.1875, 202770.4531, 202770.25, 202768.5156, 202766.6719,
    202766, 202764.0469, 202759.6719, 202755.8749, 202752.781300001,
    202752.1875, 202749.953199999, 202748.297, 202747.906300001,
    202746.0625, 202744.2344, 202743.5625, 202740.4375, 202738.8125,
    202734.5, 202727.9844, 202723.5625, 202719.1875, 202714.9845,
    202713.031300001, 202710.6875, 202710.0469, 202711.406300001,
    202714.5626, 202716.9845, 202718.718900001, 202719.5469,
    202718.734300001, 202716.4531, 202715.125, 202713.7344, 202712.093800001,
    202709.8749, 202708.875, 202709.2655, 202710.7031, 202712.375,
    202712.375, 202712.2344, 202711.0469, 202707.906300001, 202705.406300001,
    202703.0469, 202701.468800001, 202700.7656
  ), .Dim = c(
    74L,
    2L
  ), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(
    289954.375,
    289953.5, 289950.6562, 289949.7499, 289949, 289948.125, 289946.0625,
    289945.9688, 289944.5313, 289943.4063, 289941.3438, 289939.4375,
    289937.4375, 289935.1875, 289932.75, 289930.625, 289928.8125,
    289928.25, 289926.7188, 289925.5313, 289925.7813, 289925.625,
    289925.4063, 289925.1251, 289924.625, 202872.75, 202872.031400001,
    202868.7031, 202867.343699999, 202864.906199999, 202861.515699999,
    202858.297, 202854.406300001, 202851.9375, 202849.468800001,
    202847.703, 202846.75, 202845.4531, 202843.6719, 202843.0625,
    202841.593900001, 202839.7344, 202839.2344, 202838, 202835.9375,
    202832.875, 202825.7344, 202822.9531, 202819.4531, 202817.531300001
  ), .Dim = c(25L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(
    290042.6563, 290042.3437, 290041.5313, 290038.4376,
    290037.625, 290036.5313, 290035.5313, 290034.8438, 290034.5313,
    290033.7188, 290032.9375, 290032.125, 290030.3437, 290030.0313,
    290028.625, 290027.5626, 290027.3438, 290026.7188, 290024.5313,
    290023.625, 290020.625, 290018.0001, 290014.9375, 290012.0938,
    290008.5625, 290004.375, 290000.0001, 289999.875, 289997.625,
    289993.7188, 289990.5, 289987.1562, 289985.4063, 289980.375,
    289973.3124, 289966.375, 289961.8438, 289959, 289954.375,
    202884.0625, 202884.25, 202884.843800001, 202888.4531, 202889.75,
    202891.0469, 202892.0469, 202892.656300001, 202892.843800001,
    202893.2501, 202893.5469, 202893.656300001, 202893.4531,
    202893.4531, 202893.343699999, 202893.093800001, 202893.0469,
    202892.843800001, 202891.953199999, 202891.5469, 202889.843800001,
    202888.218800001, 202885.1094, 202880.9219, 202877.5625,
    202873.968800001, 202872.5469, 202872.5156, 202872.625, 202874.5469,
    202876.734300001, 202878.1719, 202877.953199999, 202876.3125,
    202873.468800001, 202872.031400001, 202872.906199999, 202873.0781,
    202872.75
  ), .Dim = c(39L, 2L), class = c(
    "XY", "LINESTRING",
    "sfg"
  )), structure(c(
    290054.125, 290053.4375, 290052.5313,
    290051.625, 290050.0313, 290048.125, 290044.125, 290040.4376,
    290039.4375, 290036.9688, 290031.4375, 290027.5312, 290024.8125,
    290021.7499, 290020.9688, 290018.3437, 290015, 290010.25,
    290006.0313, 290002.4376, 290000.0001, 289999.2187, 289996.6875,
    289995.3438, 289994.125, 289991.1875, 289989.2187, 289987.9688,
    289986.125, 289980.5313, 289975.0314, 289970.9063, 289968.5625,
    289961.0312, 289948.0001, 289939.625, 289933.1563, 289928.3125,
    289926.5313, 289924.625, 202835.953199999, 202835.656300001,
    202835.4531, 202835.343699999, 202835.5469, 202835.7656,
    202836.25, 202836.4531, 202836.5469, 202836.5469, 202835.953199999,
    202836.031400001, 202836.625, 202837.7969, 202838.4844, 202839.343699999,
    202836.25, 202832.7656, 202832.3125, 202833.4844, 202834.4844,
    202834.8125, 202834.2344, 202832.625, 202830.625, 202828.593800001,
    202828.968800001, 202831.0625, 202833.2655, 202835.5781,
    202838, 202838.906199999, 202839.125, 202836.4531, 202830.781300001,
    202827.093800001, 202823.625, 202818.5, 202817.5625, 202817.531300001
  ), .Dim = c(40L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(
    290042.625, 290042.0313, 290041.2187, 290040.3125,
    290038.4063, 290037.7188, 290035.8125, 290033.7188, 290030.9063,
    290028.2187, 290021.5313, 290021.2187, 290014.2188, 290013.4063,
    290012.3125, 290010.0625, 290007.9375, 290005.9688, 290004.125,
    290000.0001, 289999.4063, 289998.3125, 289997.5312, 289996.8438,
    289993.625, 289993.0314, 289989.7188, 289989.3438, 289987.625,
    289987.2187, 289984.0313, 289978.125, 289977.9375, 289974.3437,
    289972.7188, 289970.9375, 289967.9375, 289965.2187, 289965.1563,
    289962.3437, 289960.5313, 289959.1251, 289959.0314, 289959.3438,
    289959.4375, 289959.4375, 289959.3438, 289959.2187, 289958.9375,
    289958.5313, 289956.125, 289954.375, 202953.781300001, 202952.4844,
    202951.281300001, 202950.0781, 202948.1875, 202947.5781,
    202945.8749, 202944.281300001, 202941.781300001, 202940.1875,
    202936.375, 202936.1875, 202931.968800001, 202931.4844, 202930.875,
    202929.093800001, 202927.1094, 202925.031300001, 202922.734300001,
    202917.2031, 202916.4375, 202915.2031, 202914.5469, 202914.4531,
    202911.4531, 202910.843800001, 202908.0469, 202907.75, 202906.75,
    202906.5469, 202904.843800001, 202901.843800001, 202901.75,
    202900.0469, 202899.156400001, 202898.0469, 202894.656300001,
    202892.0469, 202891.9844, 202889.343699999, 202887.656300001,
    202885.75, 202884.5469, 202883.343699999, 202882.5469, 202881.343699999,
    202880.0469, 202879.343699999, 202877.656300001, 202876.25,
    202874.25, 202872.75
  ), .Dim = c(52L, 2L), class = c(
    "XY",
    "LINESTRING", "sfg"
  ))
), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(
  input = "OSGB 1936 / British National Grid", wkt = "PROJCRS[\"OSGB 1936 / British National Grid\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"OSGB 1936\",\n        DATUM[\"OSGB 1936\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"Airy 1830\",6377563.396,299.3249646,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4277]],\n    CONVERSION[\"British National Grid\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",49,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",-2,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9996012717,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",400000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",-100000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"UK - Britain and UKCS 49°46'N to 61°01'N, 7°33'W to 3°33'E\"],\n        BBOX[49.75,-9.2,61.14,2.88]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",27700]]"
), class = "crs"), class = c(
  "sfc_LINESTRING",
  "sfc"
), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(
  xmin = 289713.7499,
  ymin = 202700.7656, xmax = 290054.125, ymax = 202953.781300001
), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c(
  "sf",
  "data.frame"
), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(River_ID = NA_integer_), .Label = c(
  "constant",
  "aggregate", "identity"
), class = "factor"))

pt <- structure(list(lat = c(
  202805.8942, 202836.136, 202872.9487,
  202905.3284
), lng = c(
  289912.0584, 290014.8446, 290001.2364,
  289984.9382
), id = 1:4, geometry = structure(list(structure(c(
  289912.058400425,
  202805.894199679
), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(
  290014.844597566,
  202836.136003318
), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(
  290001.236395958,
  202872.948712436
), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(
  289984.938209474,
  202905.32838227
), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(
  input = "OSGB 1936 / British National Grid", wkt = "PROJCRS[\"OSGB 1936 / British National Grid\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"OSGB 1936\",\n        DATUM[\"OSGB 1936\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"Airy 1830\",6377563.396,299.3249646,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4277]],\n    CONVERSION[\"British National Grid\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",49,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",-2,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9996012717,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",400000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",-100000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"UK - Britain and UKCS 49°46'N to 61°01'N, 7°33'W to 3°33'E\"],\n        BBOX[49.75,-9.2,61.14,2.88]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",27700]]"
), class = "crs"), class = c(
  "sfc_POINT",
  "sfc"
), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(
  xmin = 289912.058400425,
  ymin = 202805.894199679, xmax = 290014.844597566, ymax = 202905.32838227
), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c(
  "sf",
  "data.frame"
), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(
  lat = NA_integer_,
  lng = NA_integer_, 
  id = NA_integer_
), .Label = c(
  "constant",
  "aggregate", "identity"
), class = "factor"))
```

Then, I need to build an `sfnetwork` structure starting from `ln` object. I need an `sfnetwork` object for the next steps (in particular `st_network_blend()` function)

```r
ln_sfnetwork <- as_sfnetwork(ln)
```

This is the result

```r
ln_sfnetwork
#> # A sfnetwork with 6 nodes and 5 edges
#> #
#> # CRS:  OSGB 1936 / British National Grid 
#> #
#> # A rooted tree with spatially explicit edges
#> #
#> # Node Data:     6 x 1 (active)
#> # Geometry type: POINT
#> # Dimension:     XY
#> # Bounding box:  xmin: 289713.7 ymin: 202700.8 xmax: 290054.1 ymax: 202953.8
#>              geometry
#>           <POINT [m]>
#> 1 (289924.6 202817.5)
#> 2 (289713.7 202700.8)
#> 3 (289954.4 202872.8)
#> 4 (290042.7 202884.1)
#> 5   (290054.1 202836)
#> 6 (290042.6 202953.8)
#> #
#> # Edge Data:     5 x 4
#> # Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> # Dimension:     XY
#> # Bounding box:  xmin: 289713.7 ymin: 202700.8 xmax: 290054.1 ymax: 202953.8
#>    from    to River_ID                                                  geometry
#>   <int> <int>    <dbl>                                          <LINESTRING [m]>
#> 1     1     2      159 (289924.6 202817.5, 289924.5 202817.2, 289923 202815.1, ~
#> 2     3     1      160 (289954.4 202872.8, 289953.5 202872, 289950.7 202868.7, ~
#> 3     4     3      161 (290042.7 202884.1, 290042.3 202884.2, 290041.5 202884.8~
#> # ... with 2 more rows
```

and this is the graphical output

```r
par(mar = rep(0.1, 4))
plot(ln_sfnetwork)
```

[image]

The next step is the definition of several new nodes into the network structure starting from the points in `pt` object. This process can be completed using the function `st_network_blend()`. See [here](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/articles/join_filter.html#blending-points-into-a-network-1) for more details:

```r
ln_sfnetwork <- st_network_blend(ln_sfnetwork, st_geometry(pt))
#> Warning: st_network_blend assumes attributes are constant over geometries
```

This is the graphical output and you can see the new nodes

```r
par(mar = rep(0.1, 4))
plot(ln_sfnetwork)
```

[image]

Now I can define a unique ID for each edge and recover the `LINESTRING` structure

```r
ln_sf <- ln_sfnetwork %>% 
  activate("edges") %>% 
  mutate(new_river_id = as.character(1:n())) %>% 
  st_as_sf()
```

Again, this is the graphical output

```r
tm_shape(ln_sf) + 
  tm_lines(col = "new_river_id", lwd = 3)
```

[image]

I see that you want to merge the IDs 1, 3, 7, 5, 9, so I will modify the ID(s)

```r
ln_sf[["new_river_id"]][2] <- "1"
ln_sf[["new_river_id"]][c(1, 3, 7, 5, 9)] <- "2"
ln_sf[["new_river_id"]][6] <- "3"
ln_sf[["new_river_id"]][4] <- "4"
ln_sf[["new_river_id"]][8] <- "5"
```

Finally, I can merge the `LINESTRING`(s) in the same group

```r
ln_sf_merged <- ln_sf %>% 
  group_by(new_river_id) %>% 
  summarise()
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
```

This is the result

```r
ln_sf_merged
#> Simple feature collection with 5 features and 1 field
#> geometry type:  GEOMETRY
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 289713.7 ymin: 202700.8 xmax: 290054.1 ymax: 202953.8
#> projected CRS:  OSGB 1936 / British National Grid
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   new_river_id                                                          geometry
#>   <chr>                                                           <GEOMETRY [m]>
#> 1 1            LINESTRING (289912.1 202805.9, 289907.4 202799.8, 289905.3 20279~
#> 2 2            MULTILINESTRING ((289924.6 202817.5, 289924.5 202817.2, 289923 2~
#> 3 3            LINESTRING (290054.1 202836, 290053.4 202835.7, 290052.5 202835.~
#> 4 4            LINESTRING (290042.7 202884.1, 290042.3 202884.2, 290041.5 20288~
#> 5 5            LINESTRING (290042.6 202953.8, 290042 202952.5, 290041.2 202951.~
```

And this is the graphical output

```r
tm_shape(ln_sf_merged) + 
  tm_lines(col = "new_river_id", lwd = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As I mentioned, the last step can be problematic for larger networks but it depends on your use cases. If you want to read more details about `sfnetworks` check the [website](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/index.html) and the [vignettes](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/articles/structure.html).

Comment: This is excellent. Shame about the last bit though, the plan involves running it on some country scale networks.

Comment: Thanks. The last part could be automatised if you can somehow identify the edges that you need to merge. Looking at the figures you posted in your question I couldn't think of anything useful but maybe there is an easy solution. If you want to add a new question with more details about the "real problem" I can check it sometimes in the next days.