# The 'map.where' function does not provide country names from geographic coordinates

Tags: r, maps, coordinates, reverse-geocoding

My dataset assembles some geographic coordinates, as can be seen below:

```
dput(head(data))

structure(list(Latitude = c(-25.600992, -22.996431, -22.954634, 
-12.983684, -22.990209, -22.955409), Longitude = c(-48.38602, 
-43.25945, -43.062178, -38.520737, -43.191247, -43.174349)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I imported the above data into R, and I ran the following commands, in order to identify the country names based on latitudes and longitudes:

```
setwd(choose.dir())

data <- read.table("Coordinates.txt", h = T, sep = "\t")

library(maps)

data$Country <- map.where(database = "world", data$Longitude, data$Latitude)
```

However, in the new dataset, the `Country` column, instead of showing the country names, showed only NAs:

```
dput(head(data))

structure(list(Latitude = c(-25.600992, -22.996431, -22.954634, 
-12.983684, -22.990209, -22.955409), Longitude = c(-48.38602, 
-43.25945, -43.062178, -38.520737, -43.191247, -43.174349), Country = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

How could I solve this problem in order to get the country names from the coordinates I have?

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a short, representative sample of your data. Please [edit] your question and paste the output of the `dput(head(data))`. This will help users here answer your question.

Comment: Are all of these points at the coast? It seems they are just not *on land* and `maps::map.where()` does not work with coordinates in the sea. Here's a map showing the points: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjgJl.png

Comment: Would there be some function that would allow me to identify points at the coast? I believe these are referenced in islands; maybe if instead of the country names I gave the island names, it would allow me to associate them with the countries they belong to.

Comment: I guess you could map the points to the closest coastline and then identify those: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76665837/adjust-points-to-closest-point-on-a-coastline-in-r