# How does the tolerance argument for sf::st_snap work in R?

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

I am trying to snap spatial points to a street network. However, the output of sf::st_snap, specifically the way the tolerance works, confuses me.

At certain values for the tolerance, I get the expected output. For example, a low tolerance snap some points to a line but not others (bc they are further away from the lines than the threshold given by the tolerance). However, often when I increase the tolerance so that theoretically each point should be within the given distance threshhold, point that were snapped correctly before, change to unexpected locations.

There seems to be something that I am missing, but I cannot find the information.

So, here's some simple data:

```
# Create data
line1 <- st_linestring(matrix(c(0, 0, 10, 0), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
line2 <- st_linestring(matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 5), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
line3 <- st_linestring(matrix(c(4, 2, 4, 3), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
point1 <- st_point(c(0, 5))
point2 <- st_point(c(8,3))

# Create an sf data frame
sf_object <- st_sf(data = data.frame(id = 1:5),
                   geometry = list(line1, line2, line3, point1, point2))

# Set the coordinate reference system (CRS) to Projected CRS: Amersfoort / RD New
amersfoort_crs <- "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.4171,50.3319,465.5524,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.87740,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs"
st_crs(sf_object) <- st_crs(amersfoort_crs)

linesf <- sf_object[st_geometry_type(sf_object) == "LINESTRING", ]
pointsf <- sf_object[st_geometry_type(sf_object) == "POINT", ]
```

When set the tolerance to 1, no point gets snapped to a line. This is how I expected it, bc the closest lines are further than one unit away.

```
new_points <- sf::st_snap(pointsf, linesf, tolerance = 1)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = pointsf, color = "black", alpha= 0.5, size=5) +   # old points
  geom_sf(data = linesf, color = "black", alpha= 0.7) +            # lines
  geom_sf(data = new_points, color = "red", alpha= 0.5, size=3) +  # new points snapped to lines
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_sf(datum = st_crs(amersfoort_crs))
```

[image]

When I set the tolerance to 2, the first point gets snapped to the nearest line. This is again what I expected.

```
new_points <- sf::st_snap(pointsf, linesf, tolerance = 2)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = pointsf, color = "black", alpha= 0.5, size=5) + # old points
  geom_sf(data = linesf, color = "black", alpha= 0.7) + # points on lines
  geom_sf(data = new_points, color = "red", alpha= 0.5, size=2.5) + # lines
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title="Tolerance=1") +
  coord_sf(datum = st_crs(amersfoort_crs))
```

[image]

However, when I set the tolerance to 3.5, nothing changes even though the first line is now within the distance threshold. Only when I set the tolerance to 4, the second point gets snapped to the closest line. But in then suddenly the first point gets snapped to another line which is not the nearest.

```
new_points <- sf::st_snap(pointsf, linesf, tolerance = 3.5)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = pointsf, color = "black", alpha= 0.5, size=5) + # old points
  geom_sf(data = linesf, color = "black", alpha= 0.7) + # points on lines
  geom_sf(data = new_points, color = "red", alpha= 0.5, size=2.5) + # lines
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title="Tolerance=2") +
  coord_sf(datum = st_crs(amersfoort_crs))
```

[image]

```
new_points <- sf::st_snap(pointsf, linesf, tolerance = 4)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = pointsf, color = "black", alpha= 0.5, size=5) + # old points
  geom_sf(data = linesf, color = "black", alpha= 0.7) + # points on lines
  geom_sf(data = new_points, color = "red", alpha= 0.5, size=2.5) + # lines
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title="Tolerance=2") +
  coord_sf(datum = st_crs(amersfoort_crs))
```

[image]

I know there is also the potential issue that the points get snapped to the end points of the lines instead of the closest point on the line, but this is not an issue for now. I would just like to understand what is happening here.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I would just like to understand what is happening here.

Here's my attempt and my interpretation of docs.
Explaining `tolerance = 3.5` is quite straightforward, as `sf::st_snap()` behaves like PostGIS' `st_snap`, which */../Snaps the vertices and segments of a geometry [x] to another Geometry's [y] vertices/../* , `st_snap` does not really care about segments in reference geometry, it just snaps to vertexes (here: only to endpoints of line segments). And all those potential vertexes are further than 3.5 units from the 2nd point.

Distance bands for all points on lines to illustrate:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(ggplot2)

# create a set of buffers for all line points 
vert_buff_lst <- lapply(c(1, 2, 3.5, 4), \(dist) {
  buff <- st_cast(linesf, "MULTIPOINT") |> st_buffer(dist)
  buff$dist <- dist
  buff
})
vert_buff_sf <- do.call(rbind, vert_buff_lst)

new_points <- sf::st_snap(pointsf, linesf, tolerance = 3.5)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = vert_buff_sf, aes(fill = as.factor(id)), alpha = .2) +
  geom_sf(data = pointsf, color = "black", alpha= 0.5, size=5) +   # old points
  geom_sf(data = linesf, color = "black", alpha= 0.7) +            # lines
  geom_sf(data = new_points, color = "red", alpha= 0.5, size=3) +  # new points snapped to lines
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_sf(datum = st_crs(amersfoort_crs)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = -5:15) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = -5:10)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I must admit I can't really point my finger on the exact reason why `tolerance = 4` returns that exact result; perhaps that used "heuristics" leans towards vertexes that are closer to the tolerance limit. Though such cases are kind of covered in the documentation:

> Too much snapping can result in invalid topology being created, so the number and location of snapped vertices is decided using heuristics to determine when it is safe to snap. This can result in **some potential snaps being omitted**, however.

---

You can also check https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Snap.html examples to see how changes in tolerances affect output geometries. For the task at hand, perhaps `st_nearest_points()` / `st_nearest_feature()` are more suitable.

Also, if this is part of a graph problem, you might want to check out `{sfnetworks}` package; besides bringing `sf` and `igraph` togeather it also provides some useful utilities like `st_network_blend()`.

A couple of relevant posts:
[Snap a point to the closest point on a line segment using sf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292952/snap-a-point-to-the-closest-point-on-a-line-segment-using-sf/51300037#51300037)
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357661/snapping-points-outside-a-polygon-to-the-polygons-in-r

Comment: This is a really useful and interesting answer and highlights the importance of looking in the postgis docs as well as the `sf` docs. The heuristics are baffling to me as well. I thought it might prefer longer lines (i.e. snapping to main rather than side roads) but that doesn't seem to be the case. One thing to add is that if I reverse the ordering of rows in the `linesf` data frame and snap with tolerance `4`, the point at `(0, 5)` once again snaps to `(1, 5)`. Doesn't explain much for me - does it give you any more insight?

Comment: @SamR,  no , sorry,  I'm afraid I don't have any ideas that might explain why order makes a difference here.